# Two different Julia projects and their toml

Tags: julia, toml

What happens when two Julia different project toml files have the same project name and same depot path? Will instantiating one cause other's cache to go stale?

Comment: Can you create a MWE that shows the issue you are facing? That would it much easier to debug.

Comment: Also, what do you mean by depot path? You do not really mean `JULIA_DEPOT_PATH` do you?

Comment: I am setting a different depot path, but Julia is still referring to the one in home directory. I will post this as a different question.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58661665/julia-1-1-julia-refers-to-home-directory-though-a-different-depot-path-is-spec

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume by *cache* you mean the set of packages stored in a depot.

`Pkg.instantiate()` will ensure that all package versions which exist in the active dependency graph (as specified by the manifest file) exist somewhere in the depot path. In general, `Pkg` decouples the set of dependencies required by any given project from the set of packages stored in depots. This is why Julia's projects are so light: different projects are free to share dependencies so that there is no unnecessary duplication.

The fact that two different projects have the same name really has no bearing on this process.

Note: although a given project can only have a single version of a dependency, a depot is free to store any number of versions of the same package.

---

In case you are referring to the *precompile cache*: there was an issue with multiple versions of the same package clobbering each other. The [fix](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/pull/32651) should be in Julia 1.3.

Comment: I first do "activate, instantiate, 'using' every package" for both projects, then running both simultaneously with "--compiled-modules=no" causes them to fail with precompiled cache problems though both run well when run isolated. If not precompile issue, I get LoadError for packages

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58661665/julia-1-1-julia-refers-to-home-directory-though-a-different-depot-path-is-spec