# Julia 1.1 - Julia refers to home directory though a different depot path is specified

Tags: julia

I set JULIA_DEPOT_PATH to julia-1.1.0/share/julia/site-xyz. All packages are built first and then precompiled with "using" on all of them.

But when the script runs with "compiled-cache=no", I see references to home directory. What to do?
The script uses Distributed package. Should the depot path be set on all workers?

ERROR: LoadError: LoadError: On worker 14:
SystemError: opening file "~/.julia/compiled/v1.1/Ipopt/yMQMo.ji": No such file or directory

▒^▒^▒ Warning: The call to compilecache failed to create a usable precompiled cache file for Ipopt [b6b21f68-93f8-5de0-b562-5493be1d77c9]
▒^▒^▒   exception = ArgumentError: Invalid checksum in cache file ~/.julia/compiled/v1.1/Ipopt/yMQMo.ji.
▒^▒^▒ @ Base loading.jl:969

Comment: What's the value of `DEPOT_PATH` in the Julia REPL?

Comment: we have scripts coming from different users and so we set the julia depot path differently for each of them on the fly. Directly in the REPL, the paths are (~ , xyz, abc for anonymity)  ---- "~/.julia"
 "xyz/julia-1.1.0/local/share/julia"
 "abc/julia-1.1.0/share/julia"

Comment: The first entry in `DEPOT_PATH` is treated as the user depot, so that’s the issue. How are you setting `JULIA_DEPOT_PATH`?

Comment: through export JULIA_DEPOT_PATH=$JULIA_DEPOT_PATH_USER (it is a single directory). This could also be due to someone's script opening a subshell and losing the path with Distributed.jl?

Comment: Yes, that could do it. Hard to way without more context. You can also set `DEPOT_PATH` directly from Julia code.